# Swipebox: страница вместо картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую!

Установил себе плагин [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/). Интересует возможность отображения веб страниц вместо картинок, вроде так можно делать. Сейчас, когда я заменяю адрес изображения на адрес страницы, слайд бесконечно грузится и все.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как конкретно нужно изменить имеющийся код:

```
<link href='http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/src/css/swipebox.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'/>
<script src='http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js'/>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;( function( $ ) {
$( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();
} )( jQuery );
</script>
```

---

```
<a href="http://www.###.com" class="swipebox" onClick="window.location.href='#swipebox'">
<div class='webpageimage' style="background-image:url(#.jpg)"></div>
</a>
```

P.S. Находил [тот же](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368263/swipebox-loading-html-instead-of-images) вопрос на англ яз версии сайта. Не осилил(

Comment: нельзя в этом лайтбоксе выводить страницы, в англоязычном вопросе говорится о выводе html-кода в всплывающем лайтбоксе, но не страницы.

Comment: для вас подойдет colorbox, fancybox или http://sorgalla.com/lity/

Comment: Понято, благодарю!